# How can I stop NewRelicAgent writing to my trace listener?

Tags: c#, .net, newrelic

I am using NewRelic on an Azure Web App with Nancy. I am calling `NewRelicAgent.SetTransactionName(category, name)` before executing each route. Calling this writes to the trace listener, which is very noisy in my log table. How can I stop this call from logging?